# Calling C# variable in ASP.NET Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, vba

So, I've been having a hard time calling this C# variable in my ASP.NET Webpage.

```
    Employee Title: <asp:DropDownList ID="titles" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Title" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LargeEmployeeConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LargeEmployeeConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Title] FROM [Employees]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
    <%
    string title = "Manager";

    if (titles.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        title = titles.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
    %>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LargeEmployeeConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LargeEmployeeConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employees] WHERE ([Title] = ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<%Response.Write(title);%>" Name="Title" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID">
    </asp:GridView>
```

As you can see, the variable title is called in the Parameters for DataSource2.

I tested this paramaters function out with using DefaultValue="Manager", which is one of the values that the dropdown list would have. That worked.

But I do not know how to get this working dynamically.

I have tried:

```
<% title %>
<%=title%>
<%Response.write(title);%>
```

Update: This additional piece of code also did not work.

```
<%: title %>
```

Although it did work when I called it outside of the asp:Parameter Tag.

Here is my new code based on your most recent suggestion:

ASP.NET:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    Employee Title: <asp:DropDownList ID="titles" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Title" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LargeEmployeeConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LargeEmployeeConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Title] FROM [Employees]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
    <%
        string title = "Manager";

        if (titles.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            title = titles.SelectedItem.Value;
            Title = title;
        }
    %>
    Title Is: <%=Title%>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LargeEmployeeConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LargeEmployeeConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employees] WHERE ([Title] = ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<%=Title%>" Name="Title" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataKeyNames="EmployeeID">
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

C#:

```
public partial class Part1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public string Title
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="titles" DefaultValue="Manager" Name="Title" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the below should work fine

```
<%# title %>

<%: title %>
```

Moreover, if you are just calling `Response.write()` then why not call it directly in your codebehind (`.cs`) file? Not sure what's the point in calling it in `.aspx` page.

```
<div>
Data Is: <%# title %>
</div>
```

Now I understand, if not wrong your title variable is declared in a method and so you are not able to access it since it's scope ends inside method block. make sure that the variable is declared in class level. Better declare a public property to get the variable access like

```
public string Title
{
  get; set; 
}
```

In your method block just set it like

```
string title = "Manager";

if (titles.SelectedItem != null)
{
    title = titles.SelectedItem.Value;
    Title = title;
}
```

In aspx then access it

```
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<%=Title%>" Name="Title" Type="String" />
```

Comment: The first one gave an error while the second one didn't do anything... it worked the same as any of my other attempts.

Comment: Data Is: <%: title %> worked fine.
I guess my issue lies here:
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<%: title %>" Name="Title" Type="String" />

It doesn't seem to like the fact that the default value is put into the code like that?

Comment: And I'm not using the .cs code behind it because it should be easy enough just to do it this way, right?

Comment: @MichaelAdair. is your `title` a public variable?

Comment: The title variable is made in the 7th line of what I have posted. I tried making it public but it gave me errors with the rest of the code so I let it be.

Comment: I updated it with your most recent suggestion. I posted the code snippets too, I have the same issue still. It shows up outside of the ASP: tag... but doesn't show up in the parameters.

Comment: So I decided to restart this project and I went through the creation of an SQL data source and found I could create a where that pulled it's value from the dropdown box.